# Flash Air App - IOS - How To Integrating Facebook

Tags: facebook, air

I have an AIR app that I am wanting to convert to a IOS APP (using flash as3)

I have used the facebook for flash api in the past, but what theat usually entails is the app opening a new browser window to log in to facebook and authorise the app.

How can I do this using to build the app as a mobile app?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are updated versions of the same API specialized for mobile. Which will, Instead of a new window, will open the login page in a StageWebView that spans across the screen.You can find the API at http://code.google.com/p/facebook-actionscript-api/

If you want to use the same API with the new single-Sign-On method you can read my post at http://saumitrabhave.blogspot.in/2011/10/facebook-single-sign-on-for-air-ios.html

Answer (score 1):

facebook-actionscript-api in googlecode is too old. I'm try it in my project, but it failed.

Now, I use [ANE-Facebook](https://github.com/freshplanet/ANE-Facebook). It is working fine in my iOS and Android device.

There is a [sample](https://github.com/zrong/ANE-Facebook-Sample).